# DTM connectivity to SiteCatalyst

Tags: analytics

I am trying to setup DTM to report to Adobe analytics. I have pasted the header/footer code on my page and I see in fiddler that the "page load" and field level tracking is triggering DTM scripts. But I am unable to see anything in my report suite on Site catalyst. 
As per DTM documentation, I have altered the AppMeasurement.js to have the report suite ID

```
var s = new AppMeasurement();
s.account = "myreportsuiteidonsitecatalyst";

/*
 ============== DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! ===============
```

Am I missing anything? Please help.

Comment: What application stack are you using? Can you give us more details about your architecture?

Comment: I am using Java Stripes. I was under an assumption that app stack would not matter since embedding header/footer code is the only thing I need to take care of when configuring DTM or sitecatalyst. Please let me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's most likely an error in your DTM code. You can use the Chrome extension here to troubleshoot your DTM configuration: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/marketing-cloud-forum/adobe-marketing-cloud.topic.html/forum__lkzf-_dtm_switchdt.html.

In addition, there are fantastic videos here which walk you through the setup of DTM and the configuration of the Analytics tool within DTM: https://outv.omniture.com/ (under Dynamic Tag Management)

Answer (score 0):

You also have to have the tracking server information set either in the code editor window or the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem even I was facing too.

I have analyzed this problem and get something which is very helpful but not able how to rectify this problem.
As you know `sitecatalyst set s_vi cookie` in our browser which is **persistent**, with help of this cookie we came to know that *reports are reflecting in sitecatalyst reports*. But while using `DTM s_vi` is not getting set in browser and hences no reflection of reprts in sitecatalyst.

I run my pages in Chrome and found that **no cookie is being set in that browser but while using `IE s_fid`** is being created subsitute of `s_vi` when `s_vi` not able to create.

So something wrong is with this.

you can check your cookie like `_satellite.readcookie('s_vi')` or `_satellite.readcookie('s_fid')`